# How to add an arrow (pointer image) to box plot in R?

Tags: image, r, boxplot

I'm working on box plot using R. I have already plotted one boxplot and now i need to put a pointer somewhere on box plot?

```
 input<-c(1,2,3,4,5) 
 boxplot(input)
```

How to import or design an arrow image at position 1.5 on boxplot?

Comment: Since you give an arrow as example: You don't need an image for that and can stick with vector graphics. Look at `?arrows`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I want to use fancy graphics not an arrow from arrows.

Comment: You can create fancy graphics with R. But if you really want to follow the approach stated in the question I would switch tools and use Inkscape instead of R.

Comment: can i create an arrow in R?

Comment: You can draw any object as long as you got the coordinates for it. If `arrows` doesn't do what you want you can experiment with `plot(0:4/2, 0:4, type="n"); polygon(c(0,1,1,2,1,1,0), c(1,1,0,2,4,3,3), col="red")`. It's not that easy to use, but I just wanted to prove the point.

Comment: @Manish I add a new solution now to your previous question! Maybe I miss something but  I don't any relation between the 2 questions?!

Comment: @Backlin, your solution works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To place a single image on a graph look at the `rasterImage` function.  If you want to put multiple images on the graph (possibly using them as plotting points) then the `my.symbols` and `ms.image` functions in the TeachingDemos package may be helpful.